# I want to download the response as excel file, but I'm getting these weird characters as data

Tags: excel, vue.js, axios

[image]

This is the response I'm getting from the backend which is sending the excel file. I want to be able to download this data as excel file, this is what I have tried.

```
 axios
      .post(serverFetchApi, formdata, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          responseType: "blob"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response["data"]);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([response.data], {
            type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
          })
        );
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "fileName.xls");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response);
      });
```

My flask server code looks like this -

```
for file_name in files_bytestring_list:
        wb = load_workbook(file_name)
        wb.save(file_name)
        print("file name",file_name)
    print("file", file_name)
    return send_from_directory(path, mimetype="'application/vnd.ms-excel'")
```

Comment: What's actually happening with the code you've currently got?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Nilson Jacques. It downloads a 'xls' file, when I try to open it an error message occurs saying that the file is corrupted. What do you think about the image? Do you think it's bytestring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
axios
      .post(serverFetchApi, formdata, {
        responseType: "blob"
      })
      .then(response => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([response.data], {
            type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
          })
        );
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "file.xlsx");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
```

This seems to work, with a difference that responseType is not inside header but as a third argument itself. I shall update my answer here once I understand its significance. Thanks.

Comment: Exact kind of weird characters in response and was struggling for days. Finally! Thank you   However, my fix was for my react application.